# dealing with Nulls while importing data

Tags: python, pandas

How do I suppress blank lines while importing data?
For e.g. in the following example, the read_csv method will fail if there is a blank line anywhere in the string.
I can remove the blank line before importing data. But I will like to know if there is any way to do the same using pandas function.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

parse = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%y%m%d')

u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']
audit_trail = StringIO('''3|120814
7|120813

11|120101
15|111231
19|121223
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols , parse_dates=[1], date_parser = parse)
```

I am aware of dropna(how='any') But I am looking for a solution while reading the data and not after dataframe is created.

**Update**: Is exception handling supported while creating dataframe? For e.g. is the following possible?

```
parser=try: lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(str(a), '%y%m%d'); 
except ValueError: pass
```

Comment: I get the value-error if the date is 000000. How do I continue and insert rest of the data?

Comment: Does it work if you do this: `df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols , parse_dates=[1])`

Comment: Yes exception handling is supported

Comment: @shantanuo always try to use the built-ins, e.g. EdChum soln, MUCH faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in pandas, it's in your method. The method doesn't have to be a lambda, and you can define it to be robust for the data, here's an example:

```
def parse(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%y%m%d')
    except ValueError:
        return pd.NaT
```

This works well with your code example.

(And of course, as mentioned in other comments an answer - pandas can handle your dates. Use methods for cases where it doesn't)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the date parser, pandas can parse your dates fine

```
In [63]:

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import io

u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']
audit_trail = io.StringIO('''3|120814
7|120813

11|120101
15|111231
19|121223
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols , parse_dates=[1])
df11

Out[63]:
   page_id     web_id
0        3 2012-08-14
1        7 2012-08-13
2      NaN        NaT
3       11 2012-01-01
4       15 2011-12-31
5       19 2012-12-23

In [65]:

df11.dtypes
Out[65]:
page_id           float64
web_id     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

You can add exception handling to your date parser:

```
In [80]:

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import io

def func(x):
    try: 
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%y%m%d')
    except ValueError:
        pass

u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']
audit_trail = io.StringIO('''3|120814
7|120813

11|120101
15|111231
19|121223
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols , parse_dates=[1], date_parser = func)
df11

Out[80]:
   page_id     web_id
0        3 2012-08-14
1        7 2012-08-13
2      NaN        NaT
3       11 2012-01-01
4       15 2011-12-31
5       19 2012-12-23
```

and it will work fine